# Google Drive pretrained model file can't be opened for loading?

Tags: python, machine-learning, heroku, fasttext

I have deployed a demo of a product using Heroku and I would like to load a pretrained fasttext model via a file in my Google Drive. I successfully downloaded the library via my heroku requirements file.

The file I want to use to load it cc.en.300.bin which is given here : https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html
But unfortunately they only provide the .bin.gz format. So instead I downloaded the file, unzipped it and uploaded it to my google drive. Then got a link to the file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pP_XQy_svafzvbCHUXC3Tc8yUriiex1-/view?usp=sharing.

But when I run this code :

```
import fasttext
ft = fasttext.load_model('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pP_XQy_svafzvbCHUXC3Tc8yUriiex1-/view?usp=sharing')
```

I get following error via heroku logs :

```
2022-03-03T19:36:24.688000+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pP_XQy_svafzvbCHUXC3Tc8yUriiex1-/view?usp=sharing cannot be opened for loading!
2022-03-03T19:36:24.935616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-03T19:36:25.071266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm not sure why it's not loading, and also I can't really put the file because I think that would be too large (it's like 7 GB in it's .bin format). So I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need Google API client and GAuth Libraries to load a file remotely from drive.

For this case you can try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
   
ft = fasttext.load_model(urlopen("https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.en.300.bin.gz")) # replace the url if it's wrong
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll connect to google drive and load it from there. Do you know if it would make my heroku app crash because it's loading a 7 GB file (I'm using the free plan)? (Also I can't just use urlopen because the file they supply is in .gz format which is not supported with the load_model() method)

Comment: IIUC, Facebook's `fasttext.load_model()` may require a *local* path for its reading operations, so the mere file-stream available from `urlopen()` may have problems. You might have to download the file locally for it to work with `.load_model()`. Also, a 7GB model tends to take at least that much addressable memorty(RAM+virtualmemory) to load – and while it's been a while since I looked at Heroku limits, that might be larger than they offer.

Comment: (Also: even if you *could* rely on virtual-mem to *load* such a model, the random access patterns of typical use would mean a *lot* of swapping address space in-and-out from disk, likely making performance intolerable. For these kinds of models, you essentially always want the full model to fit in 'hot' RAM.)

Comment: I am a noob at this stuff, what is 'hot' RAM. Also, so you're basically saying that it isn't possible for me to load the model on a heroku server? And unfortunately, I am probably going to have 3 different 7GB models up at the same time, is there a way this is possible? Would I need huge servers? Is there another way to load models quickly so I only load the one I need? Or do I need to make the model smaller?